# How can I get the correlation within dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, correlation

I am stucked at getting the correlation between product groups within an order in my dataset in python. I am using a pandas data frame. I want to know if some product group combinations (e.g. shirt with shoes) correlate.

My dataframe looks like this:

| order_id | product_group | product_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 55 | 43 | 1123 |
| 55 | 41 | 5563 |
| 56 | 78 | 1114 |
| 57 | 50 | 34567 |

As you can see, if the order has more than one product, the order is split into multiple rows.

I've tried to group the order_ids and use pandas corr() function, but I need two inputs for that, and I only have one (product_group).

Maybe I need something like cosine-similarity?

Thanks for helping me out on this! I appreciate any help :)

Comment: Reshape (pivot to wide) your dataframe to have one row per order_id and one column per product group (with 0 and 1s in there where 1 indicates product group present in order and 0 indicates the opposite). These columns you can then correlate with each other. You may however also want to look into market basket analysis methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following if you have a reasonably low number of product groups:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'order_id': [55,55,56,57], 'product_group': [43,41,78,50] }).set_index('order_id')
df

    product_group
order_id    
55  43
55  41
56  78
57  50

new_df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['product_group']).groupby('order_id').agg('max')

new_df.corr()
product_group_41    product_group_43    product_group_50    product_group_78
product_group_41    1.0     1.0     -0.5    -0.5
product_group_43    1.0     1.0     -0.5    -0.5
product_group_50    -0.5    -0.5    1.0     -0.5
product_group_78    -0.5    -0.5    -0.5    1.0
```

It may however be advisable to look into market basket analysis methods instead of correlations. But if you want to stick to correlations, then you need to create these indicator dummy columns for each product group as shown above.